# Combinatorial Proof with Summation Identity: $\sum_{i=0}^n i{n \choose i} = n2^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics

Must show:
    $\sum_{i=0}^n i{n \choose i} = n2^{n-1}$ using a combinatorial argument.
I have tried picking the problem apart by determining that the summation is equal to 1/2 of the size of all subsets of a set of size n times n.  But I am having trouble relating that to what each term of the summation represents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** We have a group of $n$ people. They want to form a committee of $1$ or more people (so size is elastic), with a **specified**  Chair.  We count the number of ways to form a Committee-with-named-Chair in two ways.

**First way:** We pick a Chair ($n$ choices). For each choice, we pick a *subset* of the remaining $n-1$ people to join her on the Committee.  If we count in this way, we will get the right-hand side of the identity.

**Second way:** We pick a group of $i$ people, $i=1$ to $n$, and they choose a Chair among them.  If we count in this way, we will get the left-hand side of the identity.

Comment: It really doesn't get much simpler than this.